# Error when using unserialize() function in PHP LARAVEL: unserialize(): Error at offset 1557 of 7736 bytes error

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to unserialize a large text string in PHP Laravel using the unserialize() function. The error message I'm receiving is:

`unserialize(): Error at offset 1557 of 7736 bytes`

The error occurs specifically when dealing with a large text string and the offset mentioned in the error message varies depending on the content. The total byte size mentioned also changes.

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
                @php
                    $usData = unserialize($row->agreement);
                @endphp
                @foreach ($usData as $key => $value)
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px; border: none;">
                            {{ $value }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

i tried to fetch data and get the expected results, but here is some thing unexpected

Comment: Where is this serialized data comes from?

Comment: from the database using query builder